# Can't place buttons in tabs tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

````py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# 1440x720
#1090x568'


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1152x576')
root.title("TimeTable")
#root.resizable(False, False)



background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='image/background.png')

my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack()

main_menu = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=1152, height=576)
main_menu.pack(fill="both", expand=1)


my_notebook.add(main_menu, text="Main")

background_label = tk.Label(main_menu, image=background_image).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
hide_button = tk.Button(main_menu, text="Hide")
hide_button.grid(row=1, column=1)```
````

I run the code, I see this.

[image]

So how can I fix this?
Why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you want to "fix". You've shown us what you get when you run the code, but don't explain how it's different from what you expect. It looks like it's behaving as designed.

Comment: It is supposed to show an image on the frame, and a button

Comment: Have you tried expanding the notebook to fill the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pack a widget into the frame `main_menu` the frame will shrink to contain only the widget + padding if any. You can prevent this by setting `grid_propagate` to `False`:

```
main_menu = ttk.Frame(my_notebook, width=1152, height=576)
main_menu.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
main_menu.grid_propagate(False)  # Prevents contained widgets to affect size
```